# Finding All Bold Italic in VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find and delete all rows containing bold italics (i.e. headers) in an excel macro.

Here's what I have:

```
Sub CLEARHEAD()
With Application.FindFormat.Font
    .Bold = True
    .Italic = True
End With
x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(x, 1))
Set i = .Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True)
    If Not i Is Nothing Then
    firstAddress = i.Address
    Do
        i.EntireRow.Delete
        Set i = .FindNext(i)
    Loop While Not i Is Nothing And i.Address <> firstAddress
    End If
End With
End Sub
```

It looks like nothing is being found in the range, but there are a bunch in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted excel, and the macro ran fine. Don't know what the problem was. Though there is a slight error. I had to replace .FindNext(i) with .Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True). Also the firstAddress is meaningless and should be removed as the macro deletes as it goes.